# Proposal: Merge tags: validation & data-validation

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

The two tags
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/validation/info (6 questions)
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/data-validation/info (3 questions)
have the same text.

Should they be merged, made synonyms, or differentiated?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Tag info has exactly the same description and from the terminology as well it seems they would serve similar purposes.

I think they can be merged to avoid ambiguity.

Quoting from an accepted answer on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work):

> All good tag synonyms should eventually be merged (source). This
>   retags all questions tagged with a synonym – which is not
>   automatically done when a synonym is created. As merging is not
>   (easily) reversible, it should be done with caution and only when a
>   synonym is established. Only moderators can perform a merge.

Synonymizing and merging tags will also make it easy for users when posting questions. The tag suggestions will not have duplicate suggestions. Unambiguous data really helps narrow down search criteria and results!

Comment: I'd accept this answer, but then how do I show that action still needs to be taken?

Comment: How about making searching process easier with the removal of ambiguity? Makes it easier to filter search results and provide more appropriate data to the user?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Perhaps we are talking at cross purposes: I was asking how do we flag the attention of someone with enough rep to actually implement your suggested merge with synonyms?

Comment: If you are asking about the process of merging the tag, then: The procedure for that I believe is already started by you asking this question. Now if a moderator see's it fit and reasonable they will merge the tags. Only a Moderator can merge tags.

Comment: So how does a moderator get to see this, so that then can see if it is fit or not? Should I flag "in need of moderator intervention"?

Comment: Well you can either wait for them to see this or you can try to contact them if you can find their contact information (StackExchange won't give that I guess). You can share this question and get more people to participate and if this gets more up votes and positive feedback, it will increase the priority of it and the moderators will look it up as a good thing to be done.

Comment: @TomHale Hi! I'll see about getting the ball rolling on this venture. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: Thanks @corsiKa. In future, how would I draw a Mod's attention? Flag something?

Comment: This is the way to do it, with a meta post. I just missed it. I'd say if you get a meta post that doesn't get moderator attention when you need it, flag the meta post with a custom flag.

Comment: Which tag should be the parent and which should be the child? What tag do we want to see on the question itself?

Comment: I think Validation can be the parent tag and data-validation or any other sub type can be the child!